# jest + enzyme: TypeError: Cannot read property 'htmlparser2' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, cheerio

I'm using jest and enzyme to build this test, but I'm having this error when I build it.

This is the test

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, render } from 'enzyme';

import Title from './../';

describe('Title', () => {
  it('should render correctly', () => {
    const TitleDOM = render(<Title />);
    expect(TitleDOM).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

This is the error
[image]

Versions: 
"react": "^16.0.0",
"jest": "^21.2.1",
"enzyme": "^3.2.0"

I appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: Please post the part of the component where you use `htmlparser2`.

Comment: I'm not using htmlparser2 in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue with electron native components and the solution that worked for me was isolating those components to a separate file.

You could just separate the usage of the `htmlparser2` to a function outside the component in a helper file.

Answer (score 0):

Hit this issue myself today, turns out `cheerio` (a dependency of `enzyme`) introduced breaking changes in their `1.x` version, and `enzyme` doesn't appear to correctly pin the version to avoid this.

You can see the related cheerio issues here:

- https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/1260
- https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/1261

Essentially, they're moving away from htmlparser2 by default, but there is a way to continue it's use.

I opened an `enzyme` issue about this here (which details where you could make the required changes in enzyme if required):

- https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2299

A workaround in the meantime would be to coerce `cheerio`'s version resolution in your `package.json`, which can be done by adding a `resolutions` entry like the following:

```
{
  // ..snip: other package.json things..
  "dependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    // ..snip: all of your other dependencies..
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "cheerio": ">= 0.22.0 < 1.0.0"
  }
}
```

This appears to be a `yarn` specific feature, which you can read more about at:

- https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/

If you use `npm`, there appears to be an equivalent package called `npm-force-resolutions` (though I haven't used it personally):

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions